# Access MySQL on a web-service from iOS 5

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I'm looking at ways to get information from my MySQL DB using iOS.
The DB and its PHP file work great (I have a working app for android which accesses it)
I wanted to use ASIHTTPRequest, but It gives all kind of problem when using ARC. I tried finding guide on how to create a static library for it, but everything I tried didn't work, I couldn't get it to run, getting about 30 errors regarding ARC (also from sbJSON)

I'm guessing that there are other ways, but googled couldn't help me with this. All I can find was getting info from it. But i need to be able to update it as well

Comment: Instead of downvoting and suggesting to close it, i'd appreciate if you'd explain what's wrong with the questiong. just looking for a way to access mysql from iPhone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are probably down voting because of the poor formatting of the question.

It also looks like this is your first time, or atleast new to iOS development, if this is the case avoid using ARC, as it uses a few different property flags. It can be a pain to use with Non-ARC library

> ie instead of `retain` it now uses `strong`

Also, you should know by now, if you don't show an attempt at the problem people tend not to help

**Edit**:
here are some links to getting Non-Arc Code working in an Arc Enabled Project:

http://www.seriousmonster.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/

http://maniacdev.com/2012/01/easily-get-non-arc-enabled-open-source-libraries-working-in-arc-enabled-projects/

Comment: I've used ARC before, just not with non-ARC libraries. that's why i'm looking for an alternative
I have the option of just sending the data in the address itself, but I'd prefer avoiding this, as this can allow anyone who knows that php file address to manipulate the DB.

Comment: Your question isn't about security or identity verification, also for them to make changes to your database they would require to know the format of your JSON. If you don't want unauthorised persons altering your database then i'd suggest setting up an authentication system. But I'm editing my answer to point you in the direction of getting Non-ARC code working.